# Droid Explorer - Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: droid-explorer

When opening Droid Explorer, it gives an error message "Input string was not in a correct format."

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

As the developer of Droid Explorer, I would suggest that this is more suitable as a [bug report](https://web.archive.org/web/20171227020909/http://de.codeplex.com/workitem/17573), which actually already exists.

Although, there is probably a workaround that you could do.

I have seen that this usually happens when there is a version of the SDK that was pre-release or something along those lines. The error happens when it tries to verify the SDK version. The folder names are used as the version, and when there is a letter in the version name, Droid Explorer does not like that.

Check the `android-sdk/build-tools` directory and see if there are any folders that have A-Z in them. If one does, that is the problem. For example, I have seen situations where there will be a folder called `android-4.4W`. I would suggest deleting that folder, open the SDK Update Tool and download the versions of the build tools that you want/need.

Comment: I took your advice but, I didn't delete anything! I just amended the extra letters or word off the end!
In my case, the directory ended with "-preview" instead of a "-W". Once I got rid of that Droid Explorer worked and, on the first try too! Plus, I'm pretty sure that build file will still work in Android Studio... I don't know.... I might be asking too much on that one.
I can always just add the "-preview" back on... instead of redownloading ;)