# Nothing happens when attempting any function of Droid Explorer, getting "Input string was not in a correct format" error instead

Tags: droid-explorer

When attempting to use the restore existing backup or basically any function of Droid Explorer, nothing happens.

When I click on Droid Explorer from the menu created, this is what I get.

> [image]
>
> Input string was not in a correct format.

It doesn't appear to be working in any means.

Comment: your device is not rooted

Comment: My LG Nexus 5 is rooted. So, it isn't that. The only APP I have listed with root access under SU is titanium backup, so I have to assume it has been rooted properly.

Comment: enable [usb-debugging](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/wiki/FAQ), download [platform_tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads), run `adb shell`, then `su` and grant permission. then try again Droid Explorer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Droid Explorer - Input string was not in a correct format](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134920/droid-explorer-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Comment: It seems to have made some progress. I did as you suggested with the adb shell, and also what was in the link you gave, where I deleted that folder android-44W and just installed what the sdk manager had for an update for the build-tools and updates of what i already had. The error has changed though:  it now says "could not find a part of the path" and points to c:\programdata\droidexplorer\assets I cannot post the exact screen cap of it here. it seems to be looking for a [default].png in that folder to move forward. that folder doesn't seem to exist on my system.

Comment: sorry i am not willing to install Android SDK and cannot test, so best is to wait for other answers. maybe you shouldn't have deleted the folder but renamed instead. or maybe use a more maintained tool like [MyPhoneExplorer](https://fjsoft.at/en)

Comment: it is ok. i appreciate your help. i can live without the backup being restored, it was just game data i was trying to get, nothing i consider important. thank you though. it was worth a shot.